# vue-pdf not working in built Vue / Flask app

Tags: vue.js, flask, vue-pdf

[vue-pdf](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf) works (I see the rendered PDF) when I'm running the Vue app in hot-reload mode, but when I build the project, it doesn't work (the PDF doesn't show up), and I see an error in the console:

`GET http://client.resolutewl.com/bfa0c7848d81ecc3380c.worker.js 404 (NOT FOUND)`

---

How the webpage looks when running the Vue app in hot-reload mode:

[image]

---

How it looks when using the built code (including the error message):

[image]

---

#### Possibly-related links

- [Vue pdf not working in chrome after build](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf/issues/161)
- [Absolute path for worker.js](https://github.com/FranckFreiburger/vue-pdf/issues/23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding a custom Flask route that handled requests for files ending in `worker.js` and looked in the correct folder for that file:

```
from flask import send_from_directory

@<YOUR-BLUEPRINT>.route('/<worker_file_name>.worker.js')
def worker_file(worker_file_name):
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(<PATH-TO-YOUR-TOP-LEVEL-DIRECTORY>, 'dist'),
                               '{}.worker.js'.format(worker_file_name),
                               mimetype='text/javascript')
```

---

This problem was happening because the blueprint in my Flask app handling the Vue app's HTML/JS was configured to look for templates (including the Vue app's `index.html` file) in the `./dist/` folder, and the static files in `./dist/static/` folder, and this was allowing the Vue app to work, but there was nothing in the Flask configuration telling it how to handle a request for the `worker.js` file (`worker-loader` creates those `worker.js` files and is a dependency of `vue-pdf`).

[image]